# Google sign in with Flutter on Android Studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, google-signin

I've been looking for an answer for way too long. I am trying to implement the google sign in method with flutter and firebase so that I can access my google agenda via the google API afterwards. I get the following error: E/FirebaseInstanceId( 6925): Google Play services missing or without correct permission.

Even with the code of this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaFI6bVI_NY&t=239s I get the error.

So you can assume my code is the same as her.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using emulator to run this code?

Comment: I am using a AVD, so yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probable reason you are facing this error is because your Emulator does not have Google Play services Installed,

So try checking avd manager and see if the emulator you are running has Play Store Services installed.

You can check that by the icon like shown below:

[image]

If there is no Play Store service installed on existing emulator then create a new device having Play Store Services.